# vmware workstation Player No internet connection

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm using vmware workstation 14 Player, there is no option for  Virtual Network Editor in VMPlayer. There are several sites which are saying to open the network editor. As I could not find network editor I'm using VM Player 14. Please view the screenshot for better understating.

[image]

Here you can see there is no option for network editor and when I click edit virtual machine setting I get the following Box
 [image]

Here you can see I've selected NAT, but still internet is not working inside VMware. If anyone could help with this.

I was following this video but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2j3nyl4muQ

but here the person is usning VMware and not the vmware workstation player.
[image] 
Inside preferences I see the following but nothing related to network settings etc
Inside my virtual machine which is a Windows Server 2012 the network adapter shows the following

[image]

Comment: Please show us what can you see inside the machine. Imagining it was a Linux Ubuntu, for example, you could check if the network adapter was working properly.
You have selected NAT, but have you pressed `OK`? XD Because it still shows `bridged`

Comment: Please view the images now

Comment: it is windows server 2012 vm

Comment: Try asking on https://serverfault.com/ . Did you install vmware tools in VM? Drivers from that might help.

Comment: Make sure that the nat adapter using is the same as the one in your pc.

Comment: how do I check my NAT adapter?? Can you help me out with this??

Answer (score -1):

To do what the video follows up is much better to do it in VirtualBox. Configuring your own NAT is quite easily done, whereas in new VmWare I still have not found a way to do it.

Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-uBoEW9H2Q) to understand better how to do it.

Comment: Please review the revisited question now